# Filter function with mapping and lamda

Tags: python

I wrote a function trying to compute and map the list, it works fine for this. But when I try to use a filter to filter out any integer values that are less than 5 in map result and return a list, it gives me an error "TypeError: 'NoneType' object is not iterable", can someone help me with this?

```
def compute(value):
    if type(value) == int or type(value) == float:
        return value ** 2
    elif type(value) == str:
        return value[::-1] 
def map_compute(my_list):
        print(list(map(compute, my_list)))
```

it works fine until here for the filter option:

```
def filter_compute(my_list):
    number_list = map_compute(my_list)
    new_list = list(filter(lambda x: x > 5, number_list))
    print(new_list)
filter_compute(['cup', '321', 2, ['x'], 4])
```

Want I want is that :

Example: function call:

```
filter_compute(['cup', '321', 2, ['x'], 4])
```

Expected returned output:

```
['puc', '123', None, 16]
```

Another question is that is there any other way, for example just use lambda to do all the above functions?

Comment: map_compute must return a result, not print it (this can be done additionally before returning).

Comment: `print()` is used only to send text on screen, not to return value from function. You have to use `return` for this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### WARNING

Before anything else, there is an important matter to address: Why are you checking types? It should be avoided as much as possible, particularly in a situation as simple as this one. Is your program purely for educational purposes?

You ask: *Another question is that is there any other way, for example just use lambda to do all the above functions?* The answer to that is yes, there are other ways, and no, `lambda` is not a good one.

---

### Code Review

Let's look at your code.

---

```py
def compute(value):
    if type(value) == int or type(value) == float:
        return value ** 2
    elif type(value) == str:
        return value[::-1]
```

As I mentioned above, the type checking should be avoided. The name of the function and its parameter need improvement, they're generic, nondescript and provide no useful information.

---

```py
def map_compute(my_list):
        print(list(map(compute, my_list)))
```

`print()` prints a value to stdout, you probably want `return` instead. I also strongly discourage the use of `map()`. That doesn't even matter, however, since you can get rid of this function entirely.

---

```py
def filter_compute(my_list):
    number_list = map_compute(my_list)
    new_list = list(filter(lambda x: x > 5, number_list))
    print(new_list)
```

Again, `print()` -> `return`. `filter()`, much like map, is unidiomatic. This function, too, seems unnecessary, although that depends on its intended purpose. Indeed, that code will crash on your example list, since you're comparing an `int` (5) to strings and a `list`.

---

### Solution(ish)

Now, here is how I would rewrite your program:

```py
def comp_value(val_in):
    if isinstance(val_in, int) or isinstance(val_in, float):
        return val_in ** 2
    elif isinstance(val_in, str):
        return val_in[::-1]
    else:
        return None


list_1 = ['cup', '321', 2, ['x'], 4]

list_2 = [comp_value(item) for item in list_1]

list_3 = [item for item in list_2 if item > 5]

print(list_3)
```

The two superfluous functions are replaced with simple list comprehensions. This code still doesn't make much sense and crashes, of course, the important part is how it is written.

Answer (score 0):

Change

```py
def map_compute(my_list):
        print(list(map(compute, my_list)))
```

to

```py
def map_compute(my_list):
        return list(map(compute, my_list))
```

using the `print` function will return None object from `map_compute`, which result the `number_list` var to be `None`, and will make your exception, caused by the `filter` function that want to get an iterable item, but will get `None`

Answer (score -2):

Below (Using inline condition and list comprehension).

It works but it is not very readable and I think you should avoid using this kind of code.

```
lst = ['cup', '321', 2, ['x'], 4]

new_lst = [x ** 2 if isinstance(x, (int, float)) else x[::-1] if isinstance(x, str) else None for x in lst]
print(new_lst)
```

output

```
['puc', '123', 4, None, 16]
```

Comment: I think oneline solutions for someone that doesn't really master python (or anyone that does) is a bad practice, its not reabable and changes will be much much harder

Comment: @Reznik if you read my comment to the code you can see that I think this is not the way to go...